# For loop in R to extract all line values in single row for a unique ref

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 5 columns (Ref, A, B, C, D) and 2 row (1,2) but under each row 2 there are multiple lines starting from 0 to n values for each of these 4 columns. I have written a for loop code in R to extract all the lines values and paste them across the row. But my code is skipping the value in 0th line.

[Excel data entry format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5beVl.png)
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IY5j.png)

Files (dataset, output, supporting file) can be found here:[[https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wfBs9oTpHuxhLeXvjLp_sLnvnZSO7Bk9?usp=sharing](https://stackoverflow.com)]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

```
library(dplyr)

# Import the data from the CSV file
data <- read.csv("/file path/data.csv")

EUR <- data.frame(Ref = data$Value[data$Column == "A" & data$Row == '1'])

Investment_strategies <- data[data$Row == '2', ]
Investment_strategies <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Line >= 0, ]
line_count <- length(Investment_strategies[, "Row"])

line_num <- 0
for (line in seq_len(line_count)) {
  col_suffix <- paste0("_", line_num)

temp_col_A <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column == "A" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, ][match(EUR[,"Ref"], 
              Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column=="A" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, 'Ref']), 'Value']
  
temp_col_B <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column == "B" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, ][match(EUR[,"Ref"], 
              Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column=="B" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, 'Ref']), 'Value']
  
temp_col_C <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column == "C" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, ][match(EUR[,"Ref"], 
              Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column=="C" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, 'Ref']), 'Value']
  
temp_col_D <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column == "D" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, ][match(EUR[,"Ref"], 
              Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column=="D" & Investment_strategies$Row=='2'& Investment_strategies$Line == line, 'Ref']), 'Value']

  if (any(!is.na(temp_col_A)) || any(!is.na(temp_col_B)) || any(!is.na(temp_col_C)) || any(!is.na(temp_col_D))) {
    EUR[, paste0("Strategy", col_suffix)] <- temp_col_A
    EUR[, paste0("Primary", col_suffix)] <- temp_col_B
    EUR[, paste0("Value", col_suffix)] <- temp_col_C
    EUR[, paste0("Other Strategy", col_suffix)] <- temp_col_D
    
    line_num <- line_num + 1
  }
  
  if (line_num > line_count) {
    break
  }
}

write.csv(EUR, "/file path/output.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

# Import the data from the CSV file
data <- read.csv("/file path/data.csv")

EUR <- data.frame(Ref = data$Value[data$Column == "A" & data$Row == '1'])

Investment_strategies <- data[data$Row == '2', ]
Investment_strategies <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Line >= 0, ]
line_count <- length(Investment_strategies[, "Row"])

line_num <- 0
temp_col_A <- vector("list", line_count)
temp_col_B <- vector("list", line_count)

for (line in seq_len(line_count)) {
  col_suffix <- paste0("_", line_num)

  temp_col_A[[line]] <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column == "A" &
                                             Investment_strategies$Row == '2' &
                                             Investment_strategies$Line == line, ] %>%
    filter(Ref %in% EUR$Ref) %>%
    select(Value)

  temp_col_B[[line]] <- Investment_strategies[Investment_strategies$Column == "B" &
                                             Investment_strategies$Row == '2' &
                                             Investment_strategies$Line == line, ] %>%
    filter(Ref %in% EUR$Ref) %>%
    select(Value)

  line_num <- line_num + 1
}

# Combine the values from each line into a single row
combined_values_A <- do.call(cbind, temp_col_A)
combined_values_B <- do.call(cbind, temp_col_B)

# Rename the columns
colnames(combined_values_A) <- paste0("A", 1:line_count)
colnames(combined_values_B) <- paste0("B", 1:line_count)

# Combine the extracted values with the EUR data
result <- cbind(EUR, combined_values_A, combined_values_B)
```

This updated code creates two lists, temp_col_A and temp_col_B, to store the values for column A and B, respectively, for each line. The code iterates over each line, filters the data based on the conditions, and stores the values in the corresponding list. Finally, the extracted values are combined into a single row, with column names appended with the line number, and then combined with the EUR data.

Comment: Thanks for the response but df dimentions don't match.
> dim (EUR)
[1] 11  1
> dim(Investment_strategies)
[1] 179   5

> # Combine the values from each line into a single row
> combined_values_A <- do.call(cbind, temp_col_A)

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 4, 3, 1, 0